# Concat NULL with Varchar SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, select-insert

I would like to ask how can I concatenate a `nvarchar` column with `NULL` without getting `NULL`? I would like to create an `INSERT` script using `SELECT`, but when any of the values is `NULL`, I get only `NULL`.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblParameterKey 
                   WHERE keyNames='''
        + CAST(ISNULL([keyNames], 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(255)) + ''')
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO tblParameterKey VALUES(''' + CAST(ISNULL([keyNames], 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(255))+''')
     END'
FROM tblParameterKey
```

This query returns correct insert inly when value is not null. If value is null it returns insert with 'NULL' which is not correct because it will be inserted as varchar and not as null value. If I remove ' ' the whole result will become null.

Comment: Can you not check if `keyNames` is null before performing the query?

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury if i remove it, whole result will be null. That's because + works as in math and stupid sql server is trying to add NULL to rest of the string therefore resulting in NULL.

Comment: I see, is `keyNames` coming from the tblParamaterKey table?

Comment: Sorry ,where is `keyNames` coming from?

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury yes, it's column of that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Maybe put the `NULLIF` statement inside the query string that way it will be `null` instead of `string null`.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblParameterKey 
                   WHERE keyNames=NULLIF('''
        + [keyNames] + ''', 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(255))
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO tblParameterKey VALUES(NULLIF(''' + [keyNames]+''', 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(255))
     END'
FROM tblParameterKey
```

Comment: that won't work, this is just and example query, there is many columns and some of then are nullable and i need insert scripts for whole table, so i need null values.

Comment: That will do the same thing as giving NULL instead of 'NULL' into ISNULL function, whole result will be null.

Comment: Edited my answer @Nogi

Comment: For now it looks like it will workt, you just need to go with
+CAST(ISNULL([keyNames],'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(255))+

instead of +keyNames+

because it would again result into NULL. this way it will generate 

INSERT INTO tblParameterKey VALUES(NULLIF('NULL', 'NULL'))

Thank you!